# TI-Nspire: Transmit Parameters to Func/Prog

Tags: matrix, ti-nspire

**The Background**
I'm trying to program a function for **TI-Nspire CAS** Handheld. The function should determine the properties of one or more matrices like orthonormality.

**The Problem**
I don't know how to transmit the matrices as parameters to the function. Does someone know if it's possible, or know any syntax example?

(I was linked here from following site: 
http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/forum/t-1150809/parameters-ti-nspire-cas)

Comment: It looks like you can use Lua to program it. Look up passing matrices as parameters in Lua.

Comment: Are you using TI-basic or Lua?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends:

If you are trying to do in TI-Basic you simply pass the matrix as a parameter (if you don't want to do that, store it in a global variable and access it directly).

If you are doing it from a Lua program, it's a little more complicated, because TI-Basic doesn't support tables inside matrices, while Lua does. For example, you could try `math.eval("MyCalculatorFunction({{1,2},{3,4}})")` which would call the TI-Basicfunction "MyCalculatorFunction" with the 2x2 matrix:
[1 2]
[3 4]. But you CANNOT do `math.eval("MyCalculatorFunction({{{1}}})")`, because TI-Basic doesn't support 3D Matrices.

Also, from a Lua script you can only call TI-Basic FUNCTIONS (NOT PROGRAMS). That means, you can't do TI-Basic graphics or pop-up windows from a Lua script.

Answer (score 1):

Functions defined normally can take matrices as arguments.
Here is a screenshot from a Notes window:

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with the second line define? The green "false" is a comment, isn't it?

Comment: The blue is the input, the green is the output.

Comment: The first line defined a function is_det_zero and the second line shows how to use it. The example demonstrates that functions can take matrices as arguments.

Comment: So the green false just means that the determinant of [[1 2][3 4]] is not zero.